# Request timeouts on DigitalOcean NGINX server blocks

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, digital-ocean

I'm getting request timeouts when I try to access any of the domains on my droplet in a browser. New droplet at DigitalOcean with Ubuntu 18.04 following Ho[w To Set Up Nginx Server Blocks (Virtual Hosts) on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [How to install a LEMP stack on Ubuntu 18.04](http://libre-software.net/lemp/)

All of the domains are set up in the Networking section for my droplet.

If I ping the domains from my Mac the domain names resolve to the correct IP address but the request times out. If I ping the domains when I'm logged in with SSH they work.

All of the domains have server blocks set up like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/congressbios.com/public;
    index index.html;

    server_name congressbios.com www.congressbios.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

There is an index.html file in the public directory of each domain root.

Running sudo nginx -t shows success

I've restarted nginx

Answer (score 2):

I've done telnet to Your server and also pinged got timeouts.

Try to open ports:

```
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
sudo ufw allow echo
```

Doing service scan with nmap confirmed that You've closed ports:

```
$ nmap -sV congressbios.com

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-05-31 02:21 EEST
Nmap scan report for congressbios.com (138.68.62.22)
Host is up (0.35s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp  open   ssh     OpenSSH 7.6p1 Ubuntu 4 (Ubuntu Linux; protocol 2.0)
443/tcp closed https
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel
```

and only ssh (22) is open:

```
$ telnet congressbios.com 22
Trying 138.68.62.22...
Connected to congressbios.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your firewall? Try from a shell on the server...

```
sudo ufw status
```

...and make sure you've got port 80 open. You can find more information about configuring the firewall on an Ubuntu server at DigitalOcean here...

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04

Another option would be try to see if you can get the page locally. That will tell you at least if your nginx configuration is okay. Again from a shell open on the server...

```
curl 127.0.0.1
```

And FWIW from here, that domain resolves to an IP address that doesn't respond to pings or http requests...

```
$ ping congressbios.com
PING congressbios.com (138.68.62.22): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
```